# CSS maze game - :hover inaccurate

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a maze using only CSS. First I'm designing shapes and then I'm giving them a :hover attribute, so that when the player fails and hits a "wall" with the cursor, the corresponding shape expands and blocks the entire screen. Here's what I have so far:

```
    .square1 {
    width: 1092px;
    height: 320px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
}
.square2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 20%;
}
.triangel1{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 300px solid red;
    border-right: 300px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 34.6%;
}
.triangel2{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 250px solid red;
    border-left: 250px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 27%;
}
.square3{
    width: 400px;
    height: 280px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 47%;
}
.square4{
    width: 327px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 76%;
}
.square1:hover{
    width: 1092px;
    height: 642px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 20%;
    background: red;
}
.triangel1:hover{
    width: 680px;
    height: 340px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 20%;
    background: red;
}
.triangel2:hover{
    width: 500px;
    height: 340px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 20%;
    background: green;
}

body
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Where the shapes (square1, square2 etc...) are named as `<div class="square1"></div>` in a different file. The only problem is that the :hover is innacurate. My shapes sometimes expand when I hover 5 pixels away from them and doesn't expand when I'm right on top of them. Why is this and how can I prevent it?
PS: I **only** want to use CSS, HTML and possibly PHP.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with the example of the error? :P Thanks

Comment: i guess it happens when you over the transparent borders :(

Comment: You're right GCyrillus, that was the problem. :/ Thank you so much!

Comment: "I only want to use CSS, HTML and **possibly PHP**" wait, what? How would you use PHP?

Comment: No clue, but sometimes you guys come up with solutions that revolve around other languages so I just wanted to clarify that those are the only ones I know :)